# how to pass a int class variable from one class to another class in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a game class sub class of CCLayer where i declare a int variable gameScore in .h file and initialize/update this variable in .m class.Now I need show this gameScore value in another class when game is over.But i don't know how to do it.Infact i found severarl solution but most of them didn't work for me or i can't understand them properly.So i need a simple example of doing it.

Comment: OK,i got a solution.Suppose we have 2 class named A and B.Then in classA.h before @interface ClassA:(superclass)  declare variable int gameScore.And in classB.m before  @implementation we have to write extern int gameScore .And by this way it is possible to get value of gameScore.

Answer (score 1):

i got solution by using singleton class

Comment: Yes,singleton is the best way.